# Form used to select record from one table and use ID when adding records in second table

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have three tables: A, B, C. There is a one to many relationship between A and B and B and C.

All new records added to table A are given a unique integer ID.

When adding a new record to table B via a form, the user is first asked to select a record from table A, via a dropdown.

I am trying to figure out how to take the ID from the record in table A, and add to it, .001, to create a new ID for the record in table B. For example, if the record selected from table A has ID 30, then the first associated record in table B would have ID 30.001 The second associated record in table B would have ID 30.002 and so on.

From there, would it be possible to carry the same idea to table C? That is, the user would use a form to select a record from table B via a dropdown and then the associated record in table C would have .001 added to it. Building off the previous example, the first associated record in table C would be 30.001.001 The next associated record would be 30.001.002

I have the forms created and functioning aside from the ID creation dependencies. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like bad design. In table B it would be a better practice to have separate fields for the table A foreign key (30 in your example) and table B ID (001 in your example). If your output needs to display 30.001 it would then be a trivial matter to concatenate these fields. Are you in a position to change this design?

Comment: I'm 100% in control of the design. It would probably be easier from a reporting/data pull perspective too to keep the IDs/fields separate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it is a bad design, but if you are set on doing this:

```
LastUsedID=Nz(DMax("ID","B","ID LIKE '" & A.ID & ".*'"), A.ID & ".000")
```

Will return the top used ID (or a fake .000 one if none has been used). You can then use something like `CLng(Right(LastUsedID,3))` to convert that to a number, add one to it and convert it back to text.